# i want to remove index from array with minimum length 3 characters

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array and i want to remove index from array which is minimum length is 3 characters

```
Array
(
  [0] => #FCBayern
  [1] => won
  [2] => a
  [3] => Championsleague
  [4] => match
  [5] => with
  [6] => 2
  [7] => goals
  [8] => difference
)
```

i want to out put like this

```
Array
(
[0] => #FCBayern
[1] => Championsleague
[2] => match
[3] => with
[4] => goals
[5] => difference
```

)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(strlen($val) <= 3)
        unset($array[$key]);
}
```

The below will do what you need.

Here is a brief explanation.

1. Iterate over the loop with a foreach loop.
2. Use conditional statement to check if the length is less than or equal to 3.
3. If the conditional evaluates to `true`, remove the index from the array.

Comment: Note that you might have to use [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/mb_strlen) if you use UTF-8 characters. Demo: [`var_dump(strlen('æ')); // int(2)`](http://3v4l.org/TCP2Q)

Comment: @h2ooooooo of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will produce hte same out put as you are looking

```
  $array=Array ( 0 => '#FCBayern', 1 => 'won',
    2 => 'a', 3 => 'Championsleague', 4 => 'match',
    5 => 'with', 6 => '2', 7 => 'goals', 8 => 'difference' );

foreach($array as $newarray)
{
    if(strlen($newarray)>2)
    {
        $myarray[]=$newarray;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myarray);
'<pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function designed for this type of task which is slightly faster than using a scripted loop as it is handled at the assembly level.

The function is called :  [array_filer()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

As solution for your problem using this method is below. You can name the function whatever you want and it simply returns a boolean -- `true` to keep the item,  or `false` to remove it.

```
$array1 = Array (
    '#FCBayern',
    'won',
    'a',
    'Championsleague',
    'match',
    'with',
    '2',
    'goals',
    'difference'
);

$array1 = array_filter($array1, "myfilter");
var_export ( $array1 );

function myfilter($item) {
    return (strlen($item) > 3 ? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sample = Array(0 => '#FCBayern',1 => 'won',2 => 'a',3 => 'Championsleague',4 => 'match',5 => 'with',6 => 2,7 => 'goals',8 => 'difference');

array_walk_recursive($sample,'makeProper');
$sample1 = array_filter($sample);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sample1);
function makeProper(&$item, $key){
    if(strlen($item) > 3){
        $item = $item;
    } else {
        $item = '';
    }
}
?>
```